# Golang Printing no needed values

Tags: go, slice

I'm new to GoLang, and trying to write this program -

> The program should be written as a loop. Before entering the loop, the program should create an empty integer slice of size (length) 3. During each pass through the loop, the program prompts the user to enter an integer to be added to the slice. The program adds the integer to the slice, sorts the slice, and prints the contents of the slice in sorted order. The slice must grow in size to accommodate any number of integers which the user decides to enter. The program should only quit (exiting the loop) when the user enters the character ‘X’ instead of an integer.

So my code is -

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    mySlice := make([]int, 3)
    var input string

    for i := 0; i < len(mySlice); i++ {
        fmt.Println("Please enter a number")
        fmt.Scanln(&input)
        if input == "X" {
            break
        }

        mySlice_var, err := strconv.Atoi(input)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Wrong input")
            continue
        }

        // mySlice[i] = mySlice_var
        mySlice = append(mySlice, mySlice_var)
        // mySlice[i] = mySlice_var

        sort.Ints(mySlice)
        fmt.Println(mySlice)

    }

}
```

If I will enter for example first 4, than 5 and then 1, it will print me

```
Please enter a number
4
[0 0 0 4]
Please enter a number
5
[0 0 0 4 5]
Please enter a number
1
[0 0 0 1 4 5]
```

Looks like it prints and sorts OK, but how do I get rid of the first three "0"?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `make()` if you're using `append()`, `append ` appends to the end and does not use the allocated space. Use `var mySlice []int` and `for i := 0; i < 3; i++`. OR if you want to use `make()`, then assign values to indices without `append()`, e.g. `mySlice[i] = mySlice_var`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked

Comment: @icza 's comment is the actual answer, `for i := 0; i < 3; i++` this can be change to an infinite loop, so the program will terminate only on user input `X`

Comment: You should make the title a little more clear for others searching for the same issue

Comment: I think user123912301812939 trying to say you need to slice first 3 array of mySlice, then make for len(mySlice) + 3. it has  worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the way you want to print it ! ( Iterating Over Slice , and printed only non zero values ) , try this !

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sort"
        "strconv"
)

func main() {
        mySlice := make([]int, 3)
        var input string

        for i := 0; i < len(mySlice); i++ {
                fmt.Println("Please enter a number")
                fmt.Scanln(&input)
                if input == "X" {
                        break
                }

                mySlice_var, err := strconv.Atoi(input)
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println("Wrong input")
                        continue
                }

                // mySlice[i] = mySlice_var
                mySlice = append(mySlice, mySlice_var)
                // mySlice[i] = mySlice_var

                sort.Ints(mySlice)
//              fmt.Println(mySlice)
//Iterating Over Slice , and printed only non zero values
                for _,v := range mySlice{
                        if v != 0 {
                                fmt.Printf("%v",v)
                        }
                }
                fmt.Println("")

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```golang
mySlice := make([]int, 3)
```

it well init a slice and it is size is 3, then append 3 zero to init it

print like this:

```golang
fmt.Println(mySlice)
fmt.Println("len: ", len(mySlice))
fmt.Println("cap: ", cap(mySlice))
```

```golang
[0 0 0]
len:  3
cap:  3
```

you can init only init cap

```golang
mySlice := make([]int, 0, 3)
```

```golang
fmt.Println(mySlice)
fmt.Println("len: ", len(mySlice))
fmt.Println("cap: ", cap(mySlice))
```

```golang
[]
len:  0
cap:  3
```